# Xamarin.Forms custom font not picked up on iOS device when FontAttributes specified

Tags: ios, fonts, xamarin.forms

I'm using a custom font in our app, and have found that if I set a FontAttributes="Bold" for a Label style using the font, it works on the iOS simulator, but not on a real device.

Steps taken:
1. Added the font Effra_Std_Reg.ttf to the *resources* folder.
2. Added this to the *Fonts Provided By The Application* element in *Info.plist* and set its build actions.
3. Created Styles in App.XAML.
4. Added these styles to the XAML on my page.

**All** the above works fine for a Label with no FontAttributes set. As soon as I set FontAttributes="Bold" on either the Style or the Label itself, the system font is used insted. Note **that this works on the Simulator**.

I know that the FontFamily is the font *Name* as defined inside the ttf file - not the ttf filename.

This on an iPad running iOS 10.3.3.

My App.XAML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application x:Class="FontTest.App"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="PlainLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                                    Android="Effra_Std_Rg.ttf#Effra"
                                    iOS="Effra" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="BoldLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                                    Android="Effra_Std_Bd.ttf#Effra"
                                    iOS="Effra" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
               <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And my page XAML (extract) is:

```
 <Label Grid.Row="4"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Style="{StaticResource BoldLabelStyle}"
               Text="QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it working on the device, I had to include the bold font file (Effra_Std_Bd.ttf), and specify a FontFamily of 'Effra-Bold'.

So it appears that the FontFamily needs to be the *Name* and the *Style*.

Strange that it worked on the Simulator.